# IOS settings bundle keyboard type

Tags: iphone, ios, settings.bundle

I'm using the settings bundle for iOS 5.0 and I want to set it to type UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad but if I type that in it doesn't work.  The only options in the drop down menu are:

alphabet

numbers and punctuation

number Pad

URL

Email Address

are those the only options available if I am using the settings bundle?

Comment: A bit of common sense, mate! Which one do you think of the above  options corresponds to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad? Of course that is `Number Pad`...

Comment: Sorry, I meant I was trying to get UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, a number pad with a decimal

Answer (score 0):

There **is** that option. The `number pad` description corresponds to `UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to get UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad, my questions as wrong because I cut and paste the last thing I tried.  After UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad I tried UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad to see if that would work the same as the drop down, it did not.  I was trying to learn how the drop down options turned into a UIKeyboardType.